# throwing exception inside the java 8 stream foreach

Tags: error-handling, java-8, java-stream

I am using java 8 stream and I can not throw the exceptions inside the foreach of stream.

```
 stream.forEach(m -> {
        try {

            if (isInitial) {
                isInitial = false;
                String outputName = new SimpleDateFormat(Constants.HMDBConstants.HMDB_SDF_FILE_NAME).format(new Date());
                if (location.endsWith(Constants.LOCATION_SEPARATOR)) {
                    savedPath = location + outputName;
                } else {
                    savedPath = location + Constants.LOCATION_SEPARATOR + outputName;
                }
                File output = new File(savedPath);
                FileWriter fileWriter = null;
                fileWriter = new FileWriter(output);
                writer = new SDFWriter(fileWriter);
            }

            writer.write(m);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new ChemIDException(e.getMessage(),e);
        }

    });
```

and this is my exception class

```
public class ChemIDException extends Exception {
public ChemIDException(String message, Exception e) {
    super(message, e);
}
```

}

I am using loggers to log the errors in upper level. So I want to throw the exception to top. Thanks

[image]

Comment: From the code I can see, it looks like you should be using a `for` loop instead of a stream. You're trying to put imperative code in a functional environment.

Comment: I want to read the big file and write some elements to another file. Here what I am doing is reading the file with filters. So I think best way is to using stream

Comment: @4castle sometimes you don't have a choice, e.g. `Files.list(path)` return a `Stream<Path>` *and* throws an `IOException`...

Answer (score 2):

Try extending `RuntimeException` instead.  The method that is created to feed to the `foreach` does not have that type as throwable, so you need something that is runtime throwable.

WARNING: THIS IS PROBABLY NOT A VERY GOOD IDEA

But it  will probably work.

Comment: You should probably explain why it's a bad idea, instead of helping them continue to shoot themselves in the foot with no alternatives.

Comment: Thanks for replying. But is it good to throw generic exceptions instead of throwing dedicated exception?

Comment: No reason you couldn't throw an extension of `RuntimeException`, which is what I recommended. Also, if you make sure to catch the exception right around the `foreach` you are guarded against surprising errors bubbling to the top of execution.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using `forEach`, a method designed to process *every* element, when all you want to do, is to process the *first* element? Instead of realizing that `forEach` is the wrong method for the job (or that there are more methods in the Stream API than `forEach`), you are kludging this with an `isInitial` flag.

Just consider:

```
Optional<String> o = stream.findFirst();
if(o.isPresent()) try {
    String outputName = new SimpleDateFormat(Constants.HMDBConstants.HMDB_SDF_FILE_NAME)
                       .format(new Date());
    if (location.endsWith(Constants.LOCATION_SEPARATOR)) {
        savedPath = location + outputName;
    } else {
        savedPath = location + Constants.LOCATION_SEPARATOR + outputName;
    }
    File output = new File(savedPath);
    FileWriter fileWriter = null;
    fileWriter = new FileWriter(output);
    writer = new SDFWriter(fileWriter);
    writer.write(o.get());
} catch (IOException e) {
    throw new ChemIDException(e.getMessage(),e);
}
```

which has no issues with exception handling. This example assumes that the Stream’s element type is `String`. Otherwise, you have to adapt the `Optional<String>` type.

---

If, however, your `isInitial` flag is supposed to change more than once during the stream processing, you are *definitely* using the wrong tool for your job. You should have read and understood the [“Stateless behaviors” and “Side-effects” sections](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#Statelessness) of the Stream API documentation, as well as the [“Non-interference” section](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#NonInterference), before using Streams. Just converting loops to `forEach` invocations on a Stream doesn’t improve the code.

Comment: In here what I am doing is creating the file in given location in inside the isInitial if block, and then I am writing every element of stream to the created file.

Comment: After creating the file isInitial will be false, then its executing rest of the lines.

Comment: I dont want to write the first element of stream. I want to write all. I think you misunderstand my question. Problem is handling exceptions inside the foreach of stream.

Comment: Your `if (isInitial) { isInitial = false; /* code */ }` clearly indicates that the code will be executed exactly once, for the very first element only. Unless `isInitial` is already `false` at the beginning. In that case, the code won’t do anything.

Comment: The last part of the answer still holds. You are using the Stream API in a discouraged way and without any benefit. Being unable to deal with checked exceptions is only one disadvantage of this. Stay with a loop.

Comment: Thanks Holger, I missed } when I am pasting the code here. Now I updated it. Writing into the file should be out of the isInitial if block. Code shouldn't be execute once. It should be create file in first attempt and then write everything until complete the streaming

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130772/discussion-between-kaushali-de-silva-and-holger).